The JSON data is not captured in correct format
I am planning to call dummy json and get the product data from it for my project.
API end point: dummyJSON
API returns data in the format below:
{products: Array(30), total: 100, skip: 0, limit: 30}

The products have the following attributes:

{id: 1, title: 'iPhone 9', description: 'An apple mobile which is nothing like apple', price: 549, discountPerc and so on...}

current code I am trying:
const API_URL = 'https://dummyjson.com/products';

function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(API_URL)
      .then(response => response.json())
       .then(console.log)
      .then(data => {
        if (Array.isArray(data)) {
           setProducts(data);
        } else {
          // If the data is not an array, convert it to an array with a single element
          setProducts([data]);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching products:', error));
      console.log(products)
  }, []);


the products should be populated with the product object data from the API response, currently it is giving empty array.
I tried this
console.log(products[0].products)

apparently it works. But I want any cleaner way to do it.

Why are you trying to log the state? Just use it in your component. If you want to see the format of the response, use your dev-tools Network panel

.then(console.log)  remove this completely, it's resolving your promise with undefined

The API returns an object with a products key that contains an array of product objects. Your issue seems to be in how you're setting that data to your state.
You can try settings the products in your state like this:
setProducts(data.products);


Nice catch. It won't solve OP's current problem but will probably solve a future one
